# Manga where the MC is summoned to another world with two other people(?), but the one who summoned them is a selfish king who did so for his own gain

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I am looking for a manga where the main character (MC) is summoned by a country. They seem like they are nice, but actually they summoned them for their own gain. I don't remember fully, but the MC gets suspicious, while the other heroes seem to believe them. If I am not wrong, a girl and guy. Something happens and the MC gets kicked out, but he is still in touch with the other heroes.

Comment: Do you recall any other details about the characters, plot, or visuals? The general premise of someone being summoned and kicked out is very common in manga, and there's not much in this short description to distinguish this specific story from all the rest. Any additional details, no matter how small, could be useful.

Comment: Too little information, but "Rising of the Shield Hero" somewhat fits. MC and 3 other students got summoned to a game-like fantasy world. Their mission is to defend the kingdom from "waves", where monsters invade from a different dimension.  They are assigned a holy weapon upon arrival (sword, spear, bow, shield), MC got shield but found out historically the shield hero's shunned as a traitor and being useless. MC got tricked by the princess (who's allied with the other 3 heroes), accused of sexsually harrassing the princess, and was exiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ***[The Path of the Perfect Evasion Healer](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/cn4tvz4/kanzen-kaihi-healer-no-kiseki)***.

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/kanzen-kaihi-healer-no-kiseki):

> A college student, Sakurai Hiroki was summoned to another world to defeat the Demon Lord. And since he got “Priest” job, his starting Recovery Stat was more than enough to heal any wounds, so he dumped all of his Stat Points to Evasion. In other words, he’s aiming for an Evasion Healer who will never get hits by enemy attacks. But unfortunately, people on that world couldn’t understand his ideal! The King got angry against him and labelled him as useless almost immediately! And thus, the story of how Hiroki become an odd Healer who can even avoid Dungeon Boss’ attack with ease has started!!

A college student, Sakurai Hiroki, is sitting on a train playing a game on his phone when he's summoned to the throne room of a king in another world. Another boy, Watanabe Ren, and a girl, Takanashi Ruri, were summoned along with him, but he's apparently never seen them before.

One of the king's subordinates wants to see what their skills are, and asks them to bring up their status screens. Ren has the job class of 'Hero' while Ruri has the job class of 'Wizard,' which the king's subordinate seems very pleased with. Hiroki has the job class of 'Priest,' but refers to himself as a healer, and the king's subordinate seems happy with that too, initially. The problem arises when Hiroki decides what to do with the 50 remaining stat points he hasn't allocated yet.

He already has 100 stat points in the attribute of [Recovery] but all his other attributes were at the base level of 1. He asks the king's subordinate what the average stat values are in this world, and is informed that it's usually around 20-30 in the primary attribute of an individual's job class; anyone with 50 or more stats points in a given attribute is considered a first-rate master. So, understandably, Hiroki chooses not to put any more points into [Recovery], and instead allocates the 50 remaining points to [Evasion], raising that attribute from 1 to 51.

However, this decision confuses the king's men and enrages the king in particular. They think that, as a healer, he should've put all those points into [Recovery], and that he won't even be able to heal scratches now, and will therefore be dead weight to the other two. I think the idea here is that they never actually looked at his status screen themselves, and he didn't tell them that his [Recovery] stat was already at 100, so they probably thought it was at the base level. Regardless, he's promptly thrown into a prison cell. Two guards even try to beat him up, although he dodges all their blows due to his high [Evasion] stat.

The next morning, Ren and Ruri come to Hiroki's prison cell and inform him that the king has decided to free him, but only on the condition that Ren wears a bangle that prevents him from leaving the kingdom without the king's permission. Hiroki feels responsible for this, and tells the other two that he's going to leave and find a way to remove that bangle from Ren's wrist. In the meantime, the three of them agree to remain in contact by using each other's given names, because the king and his men only know of their family names.

I haven't read any further than this yet, but that seems to cover your description.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This was the one i was looking for  Thank you so much .